# max-height transition doesn't work and works slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm having trouble animating a div expanding. My JQuery function does what it's supposed to, but the animation doesn't appear. I have tried both `transition : all` and `transition : max-height` but none seems to work. Also something very weird happens, when i want to hide my div again. It appears that there's some kind og delay before it disappears. This delay matches the time of the animation, but i can't figure out what's wrong. Please help.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vbqc2c27/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't animate from a specific value (0px) to a relative value (100%). You need to use specific values:

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/vbqc2c27/3/)**

```
$("p").on("click",function() {
    if($("#test").css("max-height") == "0px") {
    $("#test").css("max-height","100px");
  }
    else {
    $("#test").css("max-height","0px");
  }
});
```

Change "100%" to "100px" and it works fine.

Of course, for that paragraphs 100px isn't tall enough (the text is clipped). So you may need to add a function to calculate the auto-height in pixels.

Answer (score 4):

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Netron/vbqc2c27/8/) - simple solution without delay

Fix delay solution:

Put cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) transition function for element.

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  &.full {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: but is there any reason the bug delay happens?

Comment: The delay is because you animate/transition from 1000 px to 0. So if the contents only take up 50px, the transition goes 950px without any visible result, and then it actually animates the last 50. Those 950 first pixels are experienced as a delay. (I have no clue how to fix it, I am literally searching for answers myself.)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `slideToggle()` function which is much more simplier than that :)

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbqc2c27/6/)

**JS**

```
$("p").on("click",function() {
    $("#test").slideToggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  display: none;
}
```